# Valgrind Error Log with permissions

Tags: gdb, valgrind

I am analyzing core dump issue . I have run valgrind and look into error log.But I am not able to interpret the following message. Can anyone provide some insight.
I also tried with gdb but I did not get much information. I have looked into other  thread and found that it may be centos issue. I am using CentOS release 5.6 (Final) version. I heard that glibc file is not compatible with centos 5.6 but I am not sure about this.Does anyone face this issue any time

```
==18035==
==18035== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==18035==    at 0x0: ???
==18035==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18035==
==18035==
==18035== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==18035==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==18035==    at 0x0: ???
==18035== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==18035==    at 0x47D951D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==18035==    by 0x3141CD: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==18035==    by 0x313D46: ??? (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==18035==    by 0x47CC3B2: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:62)
==18035==  Address 0x198a55e0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18035==
```

Comment: I think it is not issue with core dump.In the positive case also it is printing same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line

This usually means one of two things:

1. Either you are calling a function through function pointer, and that pointer is `NULL`, or
2. You've trashed stack, and return address was overwritten with `0`s.

A crash stack trace from GDB might help here.

If this is a stack corruption issue, try using [AddressSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (which, unlike Valgrind, does excellent job of detecting stack overflow).